# Bundle Node.JS app in an RPM

Tags: rpm, node.js

I am building a Node.JS server application for a client, targeted at RedHat EL 6.3. They want the app to be bundled in an  RPM. Basically, the RPM should:

- Install Node.JS and various Node modules (using the NPM command `npm install`)
- Populate a folder with the app files (HTML, JavaScript, etc.)
- Launch an instance of the server

I'm new to RPMs. Is that the kind of thing they can do? How easy would it be for an RPM to do those tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPM should not do most of those things. You will need separate packages containing Node.JS and each of its modules, and you will need to make the application package itself require all of those packages. Launching the instance should be done with an initscript contained in the application package. The [Fedora Project Package Maintainers page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Category:Package_Maintainers?rd=PackageMaintainers) gives a number of resources useful for packagers for both Fedora and similar distros.